# Remove suggested apps option in iOS 10

Tags: iphone, ios

As far as I can tell, suggested apps show themselves based on location.

There are two places where these suggested apps show themselves to me:

- At the bottom left of the multitask screen when I double press the home button
- At the bottom left of the lock screen

[CNET's Disable iOS 8's 'Suggested Apps' feature](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/disable-ios-8s-suggested-apps-feature/) article describes how to get rid of the small app icon appearing in the bottom left. However, this method is for iOS 8, and I am now on iOS 10, where I am unable to find iTunes and App Store > Suggested Apps.

How can I get rid of these (in my opinion) annoying little things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *may* have figured it out myself:

To keep the Siri suggestions when you swipe right or down in the home screen, but to remove the icon at the bottom left of the screen when you double click the home button go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services > System Services > Location-Based Suggestions > OFF.

Since I did that I have not seen the little icons.

Comment: This did not work for me. I get the podcast app when I plug headphones in. It did that before too, but I was able to disable it. Started again with ios10.

Answer (score 3):

Just figured it out on the today view page when you swipe right scroll all the way down click on edit and you can remove Siri suggested apps so much simpler than I expected!

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this, it is in the Spotlight Section of settings it is a feature called "Siri App Suggestions" you may turn it of using the slider located in the respective location listed above.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
- Settings
- Privacy
- Location Services (scroll to bottom)
- System Services
- Turn OFF **Location Based Suggestions** AND **Frequent Locations**

Answer (score -2):

After you change your settings, restart your phone by pressing the home button and the power button at the same time. Bc right away your settings won't change everything for you

Comment: That's not correct, you don't have to restart your iPhone to make this change.